# My code won't work unless each part is placed in a separate button?

Tags: anylogic

### The exact problem

I found out that if I have these two parts of codes written after each other in one place i.e. one button the functions related to the block `wait` (i.e `wait.get()` and `wait.size()`) won't work. However, If I have each part in a separate button everything works perfectly.

### PART 1

1- Directing agents `households` to `enter` the flowchart

```
for (Agent i: households){
    enter.take(i);}
traceln("this is 1");
```

(`enter` here is linked directly to `wait` ) then..

```
traceln("this is the current wait size: " + wait.size());
```

At this stage, the agents supposedly are in wait. However, `wait.size()` returns  `this is the current wait size: 0`. Although the agents are showing in wait at the view window [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ICCF.png). These agents are not accessible using functions like wait.get() or wait.size()

### PART 2

Therefore, this part which has to run after part 1 is not working

```
for (int i =0 ; i<wait.size() ; i++){
    collection_main_households.add(wait.get(i).getIndex());
}
wait.freeAll();
```

In short, these codes will only work in separate buttons but, I want them to work if written after each other.

### further information about the model

Basically, The model is for residential mobility among some districts. 
At the `stratup` stage in `main`, I construct and link each familiy, based on a table contains the number of members and their ages.

The way these families are constructed is based on a `household` agent that is used as a core for `linking` and moving its family members ( `father`, `mother` and `children`). So, if I moved the `household` from A to B a `message` will be sent to its members directing them to move from A to B.

The code up is just for the first two steps after households are completely formed and ready to be located in their original locations. The process is as follows :

1. I use `enter` to get the households into the flowchart
2. Then, all gathered in the temporary status `wait` before they go free.
3. With the `wait.free(this)` command I use the `selectOutPut(IN/Out)` to distribute these `households` to their original locations.
4. When a `household` enters his location (in this case a new `waitID..`)  I `send a message` to all its connected members asking them to go to the same destination using the same commands of `enterID.take(this)` and `waitID.free(this)`. At this points all these components (`household` and its members of `father` , `mother` and `children` ) should be in the same `node`.
5. I repeat the process in the case of the a `household` is willing to change its location.

I used the `collections` to go around the problem of dynamically changing and accessing the `Hash Lists` generated by using `wait.waitingEntities`. What matters is that If `wait` takeing simultaneously from `enter`  what is the way to address that?

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuT5F.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On startup the agents have not been sent to the flowchart yet, so the wait block would indeed be empty and have a size of 0.

It looks like you are trying to add households to a collection. If you want to add all households to the same collection, just use a population and associate that population with your source. Populations give the functionality of a basic collection.

In the startup code of your household agent, you could also add to a collection there, or multiple collections depending on agent parameters.

Comment: Hi Amy, Thank you for this explanation. I actually send the agents to the flowchart using 'enter' before I call the 'wait' functions. The agents are shown in the 'wait' block but, I can't access anything like 'size' or 'get'. Please check the uploaded pictures. After, further examination of the problem source. I figured out that once I put the 'enter' code with the 'wait' code in one place i.e. one button the function related to 'wait' won't work. As if the values are not released from the memory if that makes any sense.

Comment: You need to be careful with the enter blocks.  AnyLogic will not instantaneously move an agent into a block when enter is called, like you would expect with a pure Java collection.  This is because the event calendar is managing moving agents between blocks.  You can add them to a collection on enter of the wait, this way you know they are actually there.  HOWEVER, it looks like all you are doing is creating a collection based on a population and then releasing the wait.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a big problem for me because enter and wait are my main functions for the model. I have add a detailed description of what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Hi Amy, I found out that all I needed is to change the model from a  Asynchronous into synchronous modeling by using several events ordered by trigger time and re-occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have had trouble with before is the order of simultaneous events. I suggest to go to experiment and change this from LIFO to FIFO in randomness section and see if it changes anything for you.